# how to design greenplum database constructure

Tags: greenplum

i am working on designing constructure in Greenplum database.
we have many clinets which need to store data for them.
there are two ways to design database constructure. we build one database and different schemas in this database for each clients
or build different databases for each clients, which way is better?
waht is nmore ,we need to migrate  databases or schemas from dev environment to environment

Thanks
William

Answer (score 0):

William,

Either way will work.   If you are keeping multi-tenants in Greenplum and there is no data sharing, you might be better off keeping them in separate databases - easier for security and for backups.  If there is a requirement that they share some common data, then using multiple schemas in one database is the better option.

I am not sure what version of Greenplum you are on, but you should be able to backup a schema from dev and restore it with gprestore using the --redirect option to put it in the database you want it to be in.

Jim McCann
Pivotal

Comment: Jim ,Thanks for your answer.we will not share the data between clients.will it  occupy more resource than schemas  if we build databases rather than schemas for each client ? we are on Greenplum 4.3.17.1,do you mean we should build one database for one client, and build different schemas for different environment,use gprestore to do migration?